# Inline entity form prepopulate

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content-type A which has a reference field to another content-type B. When creating/editing content with type A I let the user create/edit content of type B using the [inline_entity_form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module.

In this scenario, I like to pre-populate one field in content-type B. Here I'm using the [entityreference_prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module, but when I add the field to my URL its not populated? As example, if the field in B has the name field_myfiled , I write in the URL:

```
example.com/mypage?field_myfield=value1
```

This has worked before on fields which are rendered "normally". Is there something I'm missing since the filed is rendered by the [inline_entity_form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module?

Answer (score 0):

Please try [Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) with [Entityreference prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) Module.

1. Add an entity reference field in your entityform.
2. The entity reference autofill will automatically fill reference value into field. We can load default value from URL. (`?field_name = value`)
3. Entityreference prepopulate will prepopulate the values. (you have to add existing fields for that.)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Abin. These modules has worked for me in the past when I wanted to do similar things. But I can't get them to work when the form is rendered/presented with the inline_entity_form module? Seems to have no effect and neither has the hook_form_alter function?

Answer (score 0):

These fine gentlemen had the answer I needed. Went with an custom code approach in the end.

[form_alter: Inline entity Form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133660/form-alter-inline-entity-form)